# Worklight persistent busy indicator

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I'm working on a project using IBM Worklight and any time I build and deploy my project on any simulator or device, I have this busy indicator spinner in the middle of the screen. Its always there, on every page and its there in the ios, windows, web and android simulators as well as one android device we've tested on. Has anyone seen this before and if so how would I get rid of it.

Comment: Do you invoke a WL.BusyIndicator anywhere in your code? Did you set your application to connectOnStartup=true? Did you make any changes in your code that might have triggered it? Does it happen in a brand NEW app w/out any changes by you? Sounds to me right now like something in your app specifically, triggers this.

Comment: Figured it out, jquery mobile was the culprit, I removed it and everything works fine now

Comment: Awesome, please write that as an answer with some explanation some others could benefit.

Comment: @IdanAdar I don't have enough rep to answer my own question, I'll have to wait until tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery-mobile was the problem, it was continuously displaying the indicator for seemingly no good reason. Deleting Jquery mobile fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I already used the native worklight loading.It is very good and I tested it on different platforms, devices. But it is necessary to close it when you leave the function that opened it.

Example:

```
var busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator ("content", {text: "Please wait..."});

function consult(){
busyInd.show();
//impl 
busyInd.hide();
}
```